# Cannot log in through phpmyadmin to mysql in my container

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to have one docker container with: ubuntu 20.04, on top of which I add apache, php, mysql and phpmyadmin (all on the **same** container)

What's installed:

- mysql  Ver 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64((Ubuntu))
- Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
- phpmyadmin     4:4.9.5+dfsg1-2
- PHP 7.4.3

This is the content of my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
MAINTAINER Myself
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php mysql-server php-mysql phpmyadmin
# I've set the dbuser to 'admin' dbpass to 'admin' here
COPY ./config-db.php /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php
RUN cp /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
RUN a2enconf phpmyadmin
COPY ./start.sh /start.sh
COPY ./init.sh /init.sh
RUN bash /init.sh
CMD ["bash", "start.sh"]
```

This is the content of my init.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

service mysql start
# I'm creating the phpmyadmin database here
mysql -u root --password= < /usr/share/phpmyadmin/sql/create_tables.sql
mysql -u root --password= -e "CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin';"
mysql -u root --password= -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';"
mysql -u root --password= -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
mysql -u root --password= -e "CREATE DATABASE PROJECT_MANAGEMENT;"
```

And this is the content of my start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

service mysql start
apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

I run my container through `docker build -t whatever .` and `docker run -d -p 80:80 whatever`. I can access apache2 through localhost:80 and I'm pretty sure mysql is up because my queries worked.

But logging in to localhost/phpmyadmin with "admin:admin" just **won't work**:
" Cannot log in to the MySQL server", " mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied", " Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.", " mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied"

[image: screenshot of phpmyadmin]

I have no idea what i have to do, I'm overly frustrated, and if you ask, I basically put random lines from the internet to make my bash script and my dockerfile...

Thank you

---

QUICK-FIX: For some reason phpmyadmin doesn't add the port to the request: I had to set the following in the file `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = "{$dbserver}:{$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']}";` after the port directive was set of course.

If someone has a good explanation that'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can I confirm your `GRANT` statement? You had spaces between the asterisk and the period here: `* . *` and the `TO` is a different account than you previously created. Which version of MySQL is being used inside the container? You may need to use a different command when setting the password depending on the security policy being used. Finally, is phpMyAdmin running from the same Docker container or outside the container?

Comment: @matigo It was a bad copypasta sorry, I changed the grant, I check the privilieges and "admin" has all privilieges. Nothing changed, the exact same problems. I updated all version used. **All** processes: mysql, php, apache, phpmyadmin run on the **same** container. The version of mysql is mysql Ver 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64((Ubuntu)).

Comment: @matigo it wasn't mentioned here, but I did change `dbuser` and `dbpass`  in  ./config-db.php to "admin" and "admin" and even tried to set `controluser` and `controlpass` in config.inc.php to "admin" and "admin"

Comment: @matigo I have copied your statement, it didn't work

Comment: Then you will need to dig around in your container to see what the MySQL error log is showing. Guessing wildly is a poor use of daylight 

Comment: @matigo the logs in /var/log/mysql/error.log aren't showing anything other than "ready for connections" :[

Comment: apache log show me "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200", so basically the "post" worked? But i still got an error...like what?

Comment: @matigo I found a fix, i had to write this: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = "{$dbserver}:{$dbport}"` but do you know why the `$dbport` is not added to the `host` at the login page, even though `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']` is set to `$dbport`? And now phpmyadmin is showing this: `Serveur: localhost:3306:3306` in the header...why?

Comment: That would be a different question from the original asked. You can create another question to find a solution to this if you'd like. I do not use phpMyAdmin, preferring application-based SQL clients, so cannot offer an answer.